# PHP not triggering an error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I just did a syntax like this

```
mysql_real_escape_string($var = 'Hello');
print_r($var);
```

and I got the echo of `Hello`, so I wondering is that syntax legal in PHP? if not why doesn't PHP trigger an error that is not legal?

Comment: there's no error in this code

Comment: yes it is... i actually use it often int templates instead of using a separate declaration block.

Comment: $var='Hello' was successful so you really did mysql_real_string_escape(true); (p.s. its mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: @Waygood you mean `$var == 'Hello'`

Comment: @Waygood but the function not working when I do this.

Comment: @Jack I did expect to see the function `mysql_real_escape_string()` to work... :)

Comment: @itsme does it give an error? It should actually return `Hello`, because it doesn't contain any special characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: @Jack no i doesn't, as I asked in the question, :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> mysql_real_string_escape($var = 'Hello');

That's legal, although  it won't do what you want.

`Hello` is assigned to `$var` and then the value is used as an argument to call the function.

However, `$var` **will not be escaped** this way! The return value of `mysql_real_escape_string()` will be lost.

So don't do this. The right way to do it would be

```
$var = "Hello";
$var_escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($var);

print_r($var_escaped);
```

Comment: But the function `mysql_real_string_escape` not working at all when I do this.

Comment: I think that the function is mysql_real_escape_string() :)

Comment: mysql_real_string_escape or mysql_real_escape_string?